# An Ideal which is Maximal additive subgroup is a Maximal Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

How should I prove this:

Any Ideal which is a Maximal additive subgroup is also a Maximal Ideal .

any idea how to prove it..

Comment: If there is a larger ideal, that larger ideal is also an additive subgroup.

Comment: @DanShved How do you know there exists a larger ideal which is a maximal additive subgroup...

Comment: That's not what I said at all.

Comment: You just need to apply the definitions of maximal ideals and maximal additive subgroups. The only connection between "ideals" and "additive subgroups" that you need to use is the following: *each ideal of a ring is also an additive subgroup*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathfrak m$ is an ideal whose additive group is maximal, and suppose that there is another ideal $\mathfrak m'\supset\mathfrak m$ that is a maximal ideal.

Then, $(\mathfrak m',+)$ is an additive subgroup that contains $\mathfrak m$. Can you finish?

Comment: no I can't proceed further .help...

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of maximal?

Comment: what I can't understand is if $m$ and $m'$ have same additive subgroup...

Comment: A ring $R$ is a set with two operations: $+$ and $\cdot$. But if you forget for a moment the product, you have $(R,+)$, which is a group. Well, an ideal of $R$ is a subset $I\subset R$ which must be a subgroup of $R$, that is: $(I,+)$ must be a subgroup of $(R,+)$ (this is **not** the definition of ideal, only a necessary condition). Then, if $\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m'$ have -or, more precisely, *are*- the same additive subgroup, then $\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m'$ *are the same set*. As ideals, they would be equal, too.

Comment: I'm unable to undesrtand which is your doubt.

Comment: I understood from your edit in previous comment,thanks...